# adding specific class to element on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with a simple nav bar that uses jQuery to add and remove a specific class when a certain page is active.  I want a class to append to my aLink class depending on which ID is click.  If I click on `#aboutLink` I want `.linkActive` to be added, but if I click on `#sasLink` I want `.link2Active` to be added.  The tutorials I've looked at all have a single class being added, but since both my classes are different I need a specific one to be added depending on which ID is click.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainNav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <a id="mainLogo" href="/"><li></li></a>
        <a id="aboutLink" class="aLink" href="/"><li></li></a>
        <a id="sasLink" class="aLink" href="/savings-and-support"><li></li></a>
        <a id="external" href="/"><li></li></a>
    </ul>
</div><!--/#mainNav-->
```

I know my jQuery doesn't make sense, but it's all I could come up with.  Logically I get it, but I'm lost on the syntax.

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".aLink").click(function () {
        if ($(this) == $("#aboutLink")
            $(this).addClass('activeLink');
         else $(this).addClass('active2Link');
         });
     });
```

Thanks for any input or direction.

Comment: `if ($(this).is('#aboutLink')){...}`

Comment: Add class(es) to which element(s)? Oh, and your HTML is horribly invalid: the *only* element that can be a valid child-element of either a `ul` or `ol` is an `li`. Put the `a` element *inside* the `li` elements.

Comment: add `.linkActive` to `#aboutPage` or add `.link2Active` to `#sasPage`

Answer (score 4):

```
var idToClass = {
    'aboutLink' : 'linkActive',
    'sasLink' : 'link2Active'
}

$('#nav a').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass(idToClass[this.id]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wqK8w/).

You could, instead, use `toggleClass()` to allow for those classes to be removed by a second click:

```
var idToClass = {
    'aboutLink' : 'linkActive',
    'sasLink' : 'link2Active'
}

$('#nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass(idToClass[this.id]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wqK8w/1/).

**Edited** in response to question, from the OP, in comments, below:

> How would I remove the class so that both links don't appear to be active at the same time?

There's a few ways, but because you're adding different class-names to denote the 'active' state, they're a little inefficient. The first approach is to use a brute-force method, effectively looking for all `a` elements that have a `class` attribute and setting that attribute to the empty string, and *then* adding the `linkActive`/`link2Active` class-name to the clicked-on `a` element:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    self.closest('ul').find('a[class]').attr('class', '');
    self.toggleClass(idToClass[this.id]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wqK8w/3/).

The alternative is to remove the specific classes from the elements who have their `id` listed in the `idToClass` object. This is, however, somewhat expensive in that it needs to iterate over the object, retrieving the `id`, finding the element *with* that `id` and *then* removing a `class`-name:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var id in idToClass) {
        if (idToClass.hasOwnProperty(id)){
            $('#' + id).removeClass(idToClass[id]);
        }
    }
    $(this).addClass(idToClass[this.id]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wqK8w/4/).

If, of course, you use a common class-name then it all becomes much easier:

```
$('#nav a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    self.closest('ul')
        .find('.commonActiveClassName')
        .removeClass('commonActiveClassName');
    self.addClass('commonActiveClassName');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wqK8w/5/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! =)

Comment: How would I remove the class so that both links don't appear to be active at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have ID tags to easily reference...  I think you want something more like this?

```
$(function () {
    $("#aboutLink").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('activeLink');
    });
    $("#sasLink").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active2Link');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $(".aLink").click(function () {
        var currentId = this.id;
        if ( currentId == "aboutLink"){
            $(this).addClass('activeLink');
         else if( currentId == "sasLink") {
             $(this).addClass('active2Link');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please don't ever use `$(this).attr('id')` in real code; just use `this.id`. It's supported everywhere and it's cheaper to use. And far more concise to *type* (jQuery, after all, promotes the 'write less, do more' methodology, so why waste keystrokes, or CPU time?).